# state space model) how to add a constant term in a state vector?

Tags: dynamical-systems

I am trying to construct a state-space model and ran into an issue regarding how to deal with a constant term. I have three equations as follows:

1. $ \pi_t =\tilde\rho_{t} \pi_{t-1}+\nu_t^{\pi}$ - AR(1) process
2. $\tilde\rho_t =\rho +q_{t} $   -- $\tilde\rho_t $ is sum of a constant $\rho$ and time-varying $ q_{t} $.
3. $ q_t =q_{t-1} +\nu_t^{q}$  - random walk process

In my setting,  $\pi_t,\tilde\rho_t,q_t $ are unobservables so they can be tracked by signal extractions(The Kalman filter). The observation equation is $s_t =\pi_t +\epsilon_t $.
\begin{pmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
           1 &0 &0& 0\\
           0 & 1 & 0& 0 \\
           0 & -1 &1 & -1 \\
           0 & 0 &0 & 1
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
           \pi_{t} \\
           q_{t} \\
           \tilde\rho_t\\
           \rho
         \end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
           \tilde\rho_t &0 &0& 0\\
           0 & 1 & 0& 0 \\
           0 & 0 &0 & 0 \\
           0 & 0 &0 & 1
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
           \pi_{t-1} \\
           q_{t-1} \\
           \tilde\rho_{t-1}\\
           \rho
\end{bmatrix} +
\begin{bmatrix}
           \nu_t^{\pi} \\
           \nu_t^{q} \\
           0\\
           0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{pmatrix}

Agents aim to learn the values of these parameters over time. My question centers on how to construct the state vector in this context. I have attempted to do so as described above, but I am uncertain about whether to include the true value of $\rho$ in the state vector. This is because agents are not able to infer the true $\rho$; even after processing the signal, they can only learn $\tilde\rho_t = \rho+q_t$